# How do I call an Ajax Delete in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, controller, asp.net-ajax

I'm working with an existing MVC5 web app. We have a typical index page with a delete icon except there is no Delete view. We have an Ajax Post delete in the script section on the index page. **I'm brand new to Ajax** so I AM a bit over my head in this, so it's probably something really elementary that I'm missing.

But here it is:

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: '@Url.Action("DeleteRecord")',
data: data,
success: function (data) {
if (!data) {
                    doPopStatus("ERROR", "Something went haywire in the submit. Try Again.", "modal-header alert-danger", "fa fa-exclamation-circle text-danger", "alert", "text-danger");
                                }
                  else if (data.success === true) {
doPopStatus("Success!", "The record has been removed.", "modal-header alert-success", "fa fa-check-circle text-success", "alert", "text-primary", '@Url.Action("Index")');
                                }
                  else { //if (data.isSuccessful === false) {
               doPopStatus("Delete Failed!", data.status, "modal-header alert-danger", "fa fa-exclamation-triangle text-warning", "alert", "text-danger");
                                }
                            },
error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
goReady();
                  console.error(jqXHR);
                  let errorDetails = doParseResponseErrorDetails(jqXHR);
doPopStatus("ERROR", "Something went haywire in the post. Try Again.<p>" + jqXHR.status + ": " + jqXHR.statusText + "<br />" + '<div class="bs-callout bs-callout-danger">' + errorDetails + "</div></p>", "modal-header alert-danger", "fa fa-exclamation-circle text-danger", "alert", "text-danger");
    }});
```

This is the code (earlier) in the Index page:

```
<a id="hlnkDelete" href='@Url.Action("DeleteRecord", new { id = item.ID })' data-id='@item.ID' title="delete record" class="text-red"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>
```

Finally, the code in the controller method:

```
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult DeleteRecord(int id)
        {
            Capture capture = db.Captures.Find(id);
            if (capture == null)
                return Json(new { success = false, status = "Invalid ID!" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

            try
            {
                db.Captures.Remove(capture);
                db.SaveChanges(User.Identity.Name);

                return Json(new { success = true, status = "Record Deleted" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Exceptions.Handler.HandleException(ex, System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request);
                return Json(new { success = false, status = ex.Message }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
```

There is no view for Delete or DeleteRecord, yet this code works in other pages on the same site.

It looks to me like it should all work, and we have similar code in other pages that works fine. The Ajax function is "DeleteRecord", the code earlier in the Index page calls "DeleteRecord" and we named the function "DeleteRecord" in the Controller.

Yet this is the error we get:

```
Exception: A public action method 'DeleteRecord' was not found on controller 'DemographicsDatabase.Controllers.CapturesController'.
Controller: Captures
Action: DeleteRecord
```

What am I doing wrong here, or not seeing?

Comment: is the error above in the shown in the console or is it displayed on the page? I can't determine if the ajax function is bound to the button correctly.

Answer (score 0):

This button wouldn't call the ajax function.

```
<a id="hlnkDelete" href='@Url.Action("DeleteRecord", new { id = item.ID })' data-id='@item.ID' title="delete record" class="text-red">
   <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
</a>
```

You have to bind the event like this;

1. Remove the href attribute in your html. Then add a `btnDelete` class which we will use later.

```
<a id="hlnkDelete" data-id='@item.ID' title="delete record" class="text-red btnDelete"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>
```

2. Be sure to put the script below the body tag. Then, in your script, bind the event;

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
      $(document).on("click", ".btnDelete",function(){

         var data = $(this).data("id");

         $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("DeleteRecord")',
            data: data,
            success: function (data) {
               if (!data) {
                  doPopStatus("ERROR", "Something went haywire in the submit. Try Again.", "modal-header alert-danger", "fa fa-exclamation-circle text-danger", "alert", "text-danger");
               }
               else if (data.success === true) {
                  doPopStatus("Success!", "The record has been removed.", "modal-header alert-success", "fa fa-check-circle text-success", "alert", "text-primary", '@Url.Action("Index")');
               }
               else { //if (data.isSuccessful === false) {
                  doPopStatus("Delete Failed!", data.status, "modal-header alert-danger", "fa fa-exclamation-triangle text-warning", "alert", "text-danger");
               }
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
               goReady();
               console.error(jqXHR);
               let errorDetails = doParseResponseErrorDetails(jqXHR);
               doPopStatus("ERROR", "Something went haywire in the post. Try Again.<p>" + jqXHR.status + ": " + jqXHR.statusText + "<br />" + '<div class="bs-callout bs-callout-danger">' + errorDetails + "</div></p>", "modal-header alert-danger", "fa fa-exclamation-circle text-danger", "alert", "text-danger");
            }
         });

      });
   });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest you the following modification. It is as minimal as possible to keep your code across the project a bit similar.

```js
// Put the Ajax call in a function
let deleteRecord = function(itemId){
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '@Url.Action("DeleteRecord")',
    data: {id: itemId},
    success: function (data) {
      if (!data) {
        doPopStatus("ERROR", "Something went haywire in the submit. Try Again.", "modal-header alert-danger", "fa fa-exclamation-circle text-danger", "alert", "text-danger");
      } else if (data.success === true) {
        doPopStatus("Success!", "The record has been removed.", "modal-header alert-success", "fa fa-check-circle text-success", "alert", "text-primary", '@Url.Action("Index")');
      } else { 
        //if (data.isSuccessful === false) {
        doPopStatus("Delete Failed!", data.status, "modal-header alert-danger", "fa fa-exclamation-triangle text-warning", "alert", "text-danger");
      }
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        goReady();
        console.error(jqXHR);
        let errorDetails = doParseResponseErrorDetails(jqXHR);
        doPopStatus("ERROR", "Something went haywire in the post. Try Again.<p>" + jqXHR.status + ": " + jqXHR.statusText + "<br />" + '<div class="bs-callout bs-callout-danger">' + errorDetails + "</div></p>", "modal-header alert-danger", "fa fa-exclamation-circle text-danger", "alert", "text-danger");
    }
   });
}
```

And in your view

```html
<a id="hlnkDelete" href='javascript:deleteRecord(@item.ID)' data-id='@item.ID' title="delete record" class="text-red"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>
```

Hope this help!

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately the result is that the trash icon does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Update you anchor tag and add this function and check

```
<a href="javascript://" title="delete record" class="text-red" onclick="DeleteCaptureRecord('@item.ID')"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>


function DeleteCaptureRecord(itemId)
{
 $.ajax({
type: "POST",
    url: '@Url.Action("DeleteRecord","Captures")',
    data: {"id": parseInt(itemId)},
    success: function (data) {
if (data != null && data.success) {
doPopStatus("ERROR", data.status , "modal-header alert-danger", "fa fa-exclamation-circle text-danger", "alert", "text-danger");
      } else { 
 doPopStatus("Success!", data.status, "modal-header alert-success", "fa fa-check-circle text-success", "alert", "text-primary", '@Url.Action("Index")');
}
    },
    error: function (response) {
  goReady();
doPopStatus("ERROR", "Something went haywire in the post. Try Again.<p>" + jqXHR.status + ": " + jqXHR.statusText + "<br />" + '<div class="bs-callout bs-callout-danger">' + errorDetails + "</div></p>", "modal-header alert-danger", "fa fa-exclamation-circle text-danger", "alert", "text-danger");
    }
   });
}
```